# Multiply outgoingLight with a gradient from top to bottom

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to make an effect in fragment shader... This is what I get without effects:

[image: shader base]

This is what I get by multiplying the color by a 'gradient':

```
float fragPosition = gl_FragCoord.y / screenSize.y;
outgoingLight /= fragPosition;
```

[image: multiplying fragment position y]

So I tried to dividing but the color is kind of burned by light

```
float fragPosition = gl_FragCoord.y / screenSize.y;
outgoingLight /= fragPosition;
```

[image: dividing fragment position y]

And here are the kind of colors/gradient I want (per face if available):

[image: what I want]

**EDIT**

Here is the vertex shader (I use three JS chunks)

```
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

#define PHONG

uniform float time;
attribute vec4 data;

varying vec3 vViewPosition;

#ifndef FLAT_SHADED

    varying vec3 vNormal;

#endif

$common
$map_pars_vertex
$lightmap_pars_vertex
$envmap_pars_vertex
$lights_phong_pars_vertex
$color_pars_vertex
$morphtarget_pars_vertex
$skinning_pars_vertex
$shadowmap_pars_vertex
$logdepthbuf_pars_vertex

void main(){

    float displacementAmount = data.x;
    int x = int(data.y);
    int y = int(data.z);
    bool edge = bool(data.w);

    $map_vertex
    $lightmap_vertex
    $color_vertex
    $morphnormal_vertex
    $skinbase_vertex
    $skinnormal_vertex
    $defaultnormal_vertex


    #ifndef FLAT_SHADED

        vNormal = normalize( transformedNormal );

    #endif

    $morphtarget_vertex
    $skinning_verte
    $default_vertex

    if( edge == false ){

        vec3 displacement = vec3(sin(time * 0.001 * displacementAmount) * 0.2);

        mvPosition = mvPosition + vec4(displacement, 1.0);

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    }

    $logdepthbuf_vertex

    vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;

    $worldpos_vertex
    $envmap_vertex
    $lights_phong_vertex
    $shadowmap_vertex

    vec3 newPosition = position + vec3(mvPosition.xyz);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
```

**EDIT 2:**

After @gamedevelopmentgerm suggestion to mix here is what I get:

[image: Near wanted result]

It's much better what I get but is it possible to avoid black to white gradient in background. I only want blue to white.

Comment: I think the per face needs an adjustment in your vertex shader. Can you add it?

Comment: Yep, I add it right now.

Comment: Try mix( outgoingLight, float4(1,1,1,1), 1-fragPosition ) instead of dividing.

Comment: I edited topic, have you a solution ?